# ImageView on top of SurfaceView

Tags: android

I have the following layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.linux.camtest.CameraPreview
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/camera_surfaceView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/takePictureButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

after taking the picture I do image.setImageBitmap(bitmap), the problem is that the picture is being displayed in a small area while I already set the image to match_parent, and I tried fill_parent and that didn't work also.

What I need is to have the image view to be set to the same size of the surfaceview, so when I take the picture and load it to the imageview it will cover the surfaceview

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

and add

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

to your imageView